Do symmetry assumptions determine galaxy rotation curves?
This paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.04933 claims - not yet peer reviewed though - that assuming cylindrical symmetry the vacuum solution yields flat galactic rotation curves without dark matter.
Two questions:
Are the flat rotation curves predetermined by choosing the correct symmetry?
Imagine a solar system or a protoplanetary disk which apart from the size has similar matter distribution like a flat galaxy. If correct then obviously the assumption of cylinder symmetry would according to this paper falsely yield flat rotation curves too. Or am I wrong here? Is perhaps this comparison galaxy vs. solar system not applicable?

The claims have been made before. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/722310/why-would-grs-prediction-for-galaxy-rotation-curves-differ-from-newtonian-gravi

Thanks! That seems different however, as the paper I mentioned is a vacuum solution assuming cylindrical symmetry. My concern, would it be correct to model a solar system the same way? But then the result is wrong, because here the rotation curves aren't flat. Would you agree to this reasoning?
